# ng bootstrap "^4.0.0": While the pagination controls themselves are working, their positioning is broken

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Tried to use pagination functionality by following the examples from: "https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/pagination/". I am using "NG Bootstrap "^4.0.0".  While the pagination controls themselves are working, their display is broken.  [displayed vertically, not horizontally as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhU47.png)

The following is the dependencies taking from "package.json":

```
  "name": "ng7sass",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  }
```

Have I missed something? Please help.

Comment: Actually I went back to the ng-bootstrap documentation and it states that ng-bootstrap is dependent on bootstrap style sheet. Once I added the bootstrap4 to the project, I got the expected pagination display correctly -- i.e. horizontally. We can close the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that ng-bootstrap depends on the boostrap style sheet to work properly. I have resolved the pagination display issue by adding bootstrap 4 to the project. Many thanks for your interests on the matter.